# UITabbar icon shown on simulator but disappear on Device

Tags: uitabbar

I saw another guy posted a similar and the solutions in the replies do not work for me.

I have a UITabbar with 4 items, all icons show on simulator. but when I run it on device, the third icon does not show up while others are shown correctly. It's complete the same code  &  resources for device and simulator and I really cannot figure out what's wrong.

Has anyone met the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check case of the filenames.  Simulator is not case sensitive, the target is.